# Redirection to subdirectory with no pathname of subdir

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a shared host. Default url, `www.mywebsite.com`, on that host points to public_html directory. I have build a new directory, `wordpress`, under public_html. And i want to redirect my users to the wordpress directory. **But i don't want to show /wordpress/ pathname on address bar.**

What i have tried until now with `.htacces` puts the /wordpress/ pathname on address bar like `www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/`. However i want to show `www.mywebsite.com` even if it was redirected to the wordpress subdirectory.

Comment: Put your current .htaccess rules in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In general you just point it using .htaccess but I think there are other considerations as well. There is already an article from wordpress on how to do this as this is a very common thing. That is the best place to start is on wordpress' site.

In the htaccess of the root, you should be able to do a simple rule like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /wordpress [L]
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory